# Is it possible to automatically save mailx emails?

Tags: python, email, automation, save, mailx

I would like to automatically save incoming emails to separate files. I am using `mailx` to read emails. I understand I can manually save specific emails by entering the mailx command prompt and using the `save` command (i.e. `$ save email_number out_file`). I would like to automate this process if possible but the only way I know how to save emails is to enter the mailx prompt.  I have other pyhthon scripts that will digest the saved emails. I realize that all incoming emails are essentially appended to one file `/var/mail/mail_file`, and I can parse that file. However, it seems there may be a more elegant way to do this. I have looked over the mailx man page, and unless I'm missing it, I don't see directions to accomplish this. So,

> Is there a way to automate saving mailx emails to different files? Possibly with a shell script or perl?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a couple more days of searching around I have found a solution. Namely, `procmail`. Nice instructions for using procmail can be found here: [Mail Filtering with Procmail](http://userpages.umbc.edu/~ian/procmail.html)